# How to install libpng12-0 on Debian 10 buster i386?

Tags: linux, debian

I added repository "deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main" (i used [this](https://packages.debian.org/ru/jessie/i386/libpng12-0/download)).
I started the installation:

```
sudo apt install libpng12-0
```

But the error comes out:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_i386.deb (--unpack):
Failed to install new version “/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0”: No such file or directory
Errors occurred while processing the following packages:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I extracted file `libpng12.so.0` from this package and placed it in directory `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`.

But at installation start:
    sudo apt install libpng12-0
the same error comes out.
In this case, file `libpng12.so.0` in directory `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` disappears.

If I install the package via gdebi, the error is as follows:

```
/usr/bin/gdebi:113: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 1
c = findall("[[(](\S+)/\S+[])]", msg)[0].lower()
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am our answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331803/cannot-install-libpng12-0-on-debian?newreg=797d99ca0c6f46efba44e105abb8847b).
Deliver this package from repositories Debian 7 wheezy.

Answer (score 2):

Find your needed version at https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

(for me https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng12/1.2.59/ worked)